# How can I use DestoryView() in DefaultLifecycleObserver?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

Currently, I am using this:

```
class AutoClearedValue<T : Any>(val fragment: Fragment) : ReadWriteProperty<Fragment, T> {
    private var _value: T? = null

    init {
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object: DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe(fragment) { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                    viewLifecycleOwner?.lifecycle?.addObserver(object: DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                        override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                            _value = null
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return _value ?: throw IllegalStateException(
            "should never call auto-cleared-value get when it might not be available"
        )
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        _value = value
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an [AutoClearedValue] associated with this fragment.
 */
fun <T : Any> Fragment.autoCleared() = AutoClearedValue<T>(this)
```

But in my opinion, Since we need to _binding = null in DestroyView()

init part should be:

```
override fun onDestroyView(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onDestroyView(owner)
    _value = null
}
```

But in my class, it just does:

```
override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    _value = null
}
```

But onDestroyView doesn't exist in `DefaultLifecycleObserver`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your `AutoClearedValue` is using the `viewLifecycleOwner`'s `Lifecycle`, which means the `onDestroy` is when the `viewLifecycleOwner` is destroyed...which is `onDestroyView`. Were you thinking it was something different?

Comment: Fragment has onDestroy(), and onDestroyView(). I thought viewLifecycleOwner's onDestroy() is equals to fragment's onDestroy().

Answer (score 2):

- If you use `Fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(…)`, `DefaultLifecycleObserver.onDestory(…)` will be called at the same time as `Fragment.onDestoryView(…)`.
- If you use `Fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(…)`, `DefaultLifecycleObserver.onDestory(…)` will be called at the same time as `Fragment.onDestory(…)`.

Here is an example.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(…) {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(
        object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                println("Fragment.onDestroyView() is called.")
            }
        }
    )
    lifecycle.addObserver(
        object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                println("Fragment.onDestroy() is called.")
            }
        }
    )
}
```